# Prove that $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{0}^{1-\varepsilon} \log |f\left(2-\varepsilon+ix\right)|\ dx=\int_{0}^{1} \log |f(2+ix)| \ dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, analysis

> **Question:** If $f$ be an entire function with no zeros on the line $x=2-\varepsilon$  $$
>     \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{0}^{1-\varepsilon} \log |f\left(2-\varepsilon+ix\right)|\ dx=\int_{0}^{1} \log |f(2+ix)| \ dx  $$

Now we write for $0<\varepsilon<1$ $$\int_{0}^{1-\varepsilon} \log |f\left(2-\varepsilon+ix\right)|\ dx= \int_{0}^{2} \log |f\left(2-\varepsilon+ix\right)|\chi_{[0,1-\varepsilon]}(x)\ dx $$
where $\chi$ is the characteristic function defined as $1$ if $x$ belongs to the interval $[0,1-\varepsilon]$ and $0$ otherwise.

Since $f$ is entire and non zero on the line $x=2-\varepsilon$,  so $\log |f\left(2-\varepsilon+ix\right)|$ is continuous on $[0,2]$ and hence uniformly continuous on $[0,2]$.
So we want for all $\varepsilon'>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that  $$ \left|\log |f\left(2-\varepsilon+ix\right)|\chi_{[0,1-\varepsilon]}(x) -\log |f\left(2+ix\right)|\chi_{[0,1]}(x)\right|<\varepsilon'\ \ \text{when}\ \ 0<\varepsilon<\delta$$
How do we use uniform continuity to prove this question?

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|\int_{0}^{1-\varepsilon} \log |f\left(2-\varepsilon+it\right)|\ dt-\int_{0}^{1} \log |f(2+it)| \ dt\right|\le I_1(\epsilon)+I_2(\epsilon),$$

where (for $0<\epsilon<1$)

$$I_1(\epsilon)=\int_{0}^{1-\varepsilon}\left|\log |f\left(2-\varepsilon+it\right)|-\log |f(2+it)|\right|\ dt\le\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\left|\log |f\left(2-\varepsilon+it\right)|-\log |f(2+it)|\right|$$and
$$I_2(\epsilon)=\left|\int_{1-\epsilon}^1\log |f(2+ix)| \ dx\right|\le\epsilon\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\left|\log|f(2+it)|\right|.$$

Both $I_1(\epsilon)$ and $I_1(\epsilon)$ tend to $0$ as $\epsilon\to0^+.$ Uniform continuity is used for $I_1.$

Comment: Where did we use Uniform continuity in $I_1(\varepsilon)$?

Comment: $\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\left|\log |f\left(2-\varepsilon+it\right)|-\log |f(2+it)|\right|$ depends on $\epsilon$ and (by uniform continuity) tends to $0$ as $\epsilon\to0^+$, hence so does $I_1(\epsilon)$.

Comment: Sorry, I am a begginer. Please explain that how by uniform continuity $\sup_{t\in [0,1]} |\log|f(2-\varepsilon+it)-\log|f(2+it)|$ tends to $0$ as $\varepsilon\to 0^+$?

Comment: Please explain first what is the definition of uniform continuity.

Comment: It is that given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any two points $x$, $y$ of an interval $I$ (here closed interval) $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ when $|x-y|<\delta$. But this is for a real valued function $f$.

Comment: Ok. Now, the function $g=\log[f|$ *is* real-valued, *but* it is a function of *two variables*. What is the definition of uniform continuity for $g$, then?

Comment: Sorry I don't know. Please help me. Please write a detailed answer. I will with utmost respect accept it.

Comment: Oh well, reading the last sentence of your question I thought you did know. You will have to trust me that $g$ is (well defined and) uniformly continuous on a thin rectangle $R=[2-\alpha,2]\times[0,1]$, i.e. (very similar to your definition for a function of 1 variable) given $a>0$ there exists $b>0$ such that for any two pairs $(s,t)$ and $(s',t')$ in $R$, $|g(s,t)-g(s',t')|<a$ when $|s-s'|\le b$ and $|t-t'|\le b$. Apply this to $t=t'\in[0,1]$ and $s=2-\epsilon$, $s'=2$ and this will (?) answer your question of 55 mins ago.

Comment: So if $g$ is continuous on the compact set $R$ then why are we talking about the supremum? Will maximum won't suffice?

Comment: You are right, it is the same.